# JSON_VALUE not working in old version. is there any other way in SQL to get a value from a JSON

Tags: mysql, adonis.js

So the main problem I'm having is that I really need to get a value from another table that is in JSON format, obviously I thought, well just use JSON_VALUE to get the property I want... Problem arises when I created in adonis the migration, and surprise. After running the migrations I realise I can't use JSON_VALUE because of the version of adonis server. Is there another way I can get the value?

Comment: Can't you upgrade the MySQL installation on your server?

Comment: Fetch the whole JSON document into your app, unmarshal it into a struct, and pick out the value you want. You will regret any other solution. I do recommend you upgrade your MySQL version. If you're on MySQL 5.6 or earlier, [it's already past its end of life.](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/mysql)

Comment: @BillKarwin *If you're on MySQL 5.6 or earlier* JSON_VALUE() was introduced in 8.0.21.

Comment: *Is there another way I can get the value?* There is a lot of string functions, it is enough for to solve your task. I'd recommend to create universal user-defined function, but in each separate case you may build separate specific expression, of course. Cast to needed output datatype (ex- or implicit) must be applied in the query anycase - function cannot have changeable output datatype.

Comment: Ah, right, I'm thinking of other functions in 5.7 like JSON_SEARCH().

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was easier than I'd expected. I could, because I wanted to search a String inside the JSON it was as easy as using LIKE. Example

user.settings was a JSON more less like:
'{"platform" : "windows"}'

```
UPDATE order
      SET order.platform = (
        SELECT
          CASE 
            WHEN users.settings LIKE '%mac%' THEN 'mac'
            WHEN users.settings LIKE '%windows%' THEN 'windows'
            ELSE NULL
          END
        FROM users
        WHERE users.id = orders.user_id
      )
```